# Modern equivalent of for... in loop?

Tags: javascript

I have inherited a deminified codebase as a personal project from the web archive.

There are many of these:

```
for (var keyCodeName in keyCodeByName) {
   // something happens
}
```

Is there a modern equivalent to this type of for loop which means the same thing? I get lost in "enumerable properties" when I try to research it.

Comment: `for ... of` loop?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I loop through or enumerate a JavaScript object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/684672/how-do-i-loop-through-or-enumerate-a-javascript-object)

Comment: it can depend on what `something happens` does

Comment: @Phix nope! for... in,  I haven't used in it 10 years so it's weird to me to understand, but it is all over the codebase.

Comment: What is wrong with the `for...in` loop? Why does it need to be replaced?

Comment: @Ivar never seen it in my life in any open source code or my own understanding of the language. TypeScript starts to moan at me in `strict` mode but after many days I don't get it. The same way there is for(itr) or map... I want to ditch it for something less lame.

Comment: @JaromandaX  in what context?

Comment: There are some issues with `for...in` if not used properly, [one article here](http://adripofjavascript.com/blog/drips/the-problem-with-for-in-and-javascript-arrays.html).

Comment: to iterate over keys a equivalent would be `Object.keys(myObj).forEach()`, though at first glance I don't see why would change it...

Comment: But @buzatto is that a true statement? Is it literally the equivalent? I understand that.

Comment: @Phix thank you, I will check this out.  Can someone tell me what "enumerable" means? All objects have properties. Why are some "enumerable" ?

Comment: @user1059939 I think Phix was suggesting you use a `for ... of ` loop.

Comment: @Brad but  is `for...of` literally `for...in`? Even `for...of` I can understand.

Comment: `for..in` is probably the fastest loop over any other than `for..of`, `forEach`, `Object.keys` and `Object.entries` so why change it?

Comment: @user1059939 No, it's different, but you haven't explained what it is you want to change and why.

Comment: @Brad thank you, in that case, as also others have stated, it depends on the usage... So for ever `for...in` context matters and that sucks....

Comment: [enumerable properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Enumerability_and_ownership_of_properties)

Comment: what context @user1059939? In the context of what the code is doing - I can't address every single possible scenario - the point is, there are many "tools" to iterate "something" in javascript - the best "tool" is the correct "tool"

Comment: for...in is still considered modern. It's not obsolete and there is no reason not to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest equivalent is looping over `Object.keys()` with `forEach()`:

```
Object.keys(keyCodeByName).forEach(keyCodeName => {
    // something happens
});
```

This is actually roughly equivalent to the following loop:

```
for (let keyCodeName in keyCodeByName) {
    if (keyCodeByName.hasOwnProperty(keyCodeName)) {
        // something happens
    }
}
```

because `Object.keys()` only returns *own* properties, while `for-in` will process inherited properties as well.

Many programmers forget to do the `hasOwnProperty()` check, and in most cases it's innocuous because none of the inherited properties are enumerable. So if the code you're trying to convert doesn't have the check, it's more likely that they didn't realize they needed it, not that they really want to process inherited properties. So using `Object.keys()` is likely to be closer to the intended behavior.

See [When do I need to use hasOwnProperty()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422867/when-do-i-need-to-use-hasownproperty)

Comment: This is exactly the bare bones explaination that I was after. Thank you for taking the time to write it Barmar.  In TypeScript this check is flagged in strict mode and was the missing key I needed.

Comment: object.hasOwnProperty() checks are not needed anymore due to the very point you made about inherited properties being non-enenumerable. If you are adding inherited properties that are enumerable then you're doing something wrong or you're using an old browser that doesn't allow you to change enumerablility. The only reason to still do the check is to support old browsers. There is nothing wrong with using for...in. It's more efficient than using Object.keys() with .forEach()

Comment: @PHPGuru True, and the question I linked to has a link to a web site explaining why it's not necessary. But it also presumes that people will extend `Object.prototype` in the correct way (with `defineProperty` and `enumerable: false`), which is not something you can always count on.